# why unset cookie variable when deleting cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm exploring the source code of Kohana framework, and it has the following logic when deleting the cookie on browser:

```
public static function delete($name)
    {
        // Remove the cookie
        unset($_COOKIE[$name]);

        // Nullify the cookie and make it expire
        return setcookie($name, NULL, -86400, Cookie::$path, Cookie::$domain, Cookie::$secure, Cookie::$httponly);
    }
```

I understand that the function `setcookie` will set cookie's name to `deleted` (as displayed in browser cookies view) and expire it so that the browswer doesn't send it next time. So why is the first part with `unset` is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setcookie` add cookie to HTTP **response** headers. Whereas $_COOKIE presents cookies from **request** headers. So `setcookie` doesn't affect on cookies of $_COOKIE array (on the current page load). Therefore we have to unset cookie in $_COOKIE too in order to ensure that this cookie won't present in $_COOKIE array if we'll want to get it in further (on the current page load).

Comment: ok, so why would you want to remove cookies from $_COOKIE, if it represents current request and this request contained the cookie?

Comment: I thought it should be clear) We have to unset cookie in $_COOKIE in order to ensure that this cookie removed from $_COOKIE array.

Comment: _in order to ensure that this cookie removed from $_COOKIE array._ why we do we need to ensure this?

Comment: so are we unsetting it just to avoid accidently using it during current request after triggering `setcookie` ?

Comment: @Maximus Finally you got my point! Quote from manual: `Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page load with the $_COOKIE` (here keyword: NEXT). The same may be applied to cookies removal. We can only get effect of `setcookie` on the next page load. If we want to get effect on the current page load we have to remove cookie from `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: Right, I understand that. I just couldn't figure out why I would need to use the cookie variable I deleted)

Comment: Considering the fact that this code is used in a framework, it doesn't look strange. The same cookie may be used in different places of application code.

Answer (score 0):

both are same and deleting cookie. If we remove unset, Surely it will work and delete the cookie.